# Extracting content between two defined words in python using Regular expression

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

here i am trying to extract content between pointID and point Name. As shown in below image.

[image]

```
        import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sent1 = 'Date:2020/07/11 13:53  Low Alarm OFF\nAlarm Priority:Urgent\nPoint ID0000294.AI.0017707\nPoint Name:BOM-DC3-B2-2F-Q1-TEMP 3\nAlarm:Normal\nStatus:18.6 øC'
sent2 = 'Date:2020/07/11 13:42  Low AlarmAlarm Priority:UrgentPoint ID0000294.AI.0017707Point Name:BOM-DC3-B2-2F-Q1-TEMP 3Alarm:AbnormalStatus:Analog Lower Limit Alarm 18.0 øC'
def extract_id(sent):
    lst=re.split(r'\W+', sent)
    lst=str(lst[13]) + str(lst[14]) + str(lst[15])
    return(lst)
```

Here with first `sent1` i am able to extract content between `pointid` but `point Name` But with the `sent2` i am unable to do so . Why because i am splitting the complete sentence in a list and then fetching the list index 13/14/15. which is not same for `sent2`. Need a solution using Regular expression how can fetch the content between `Point ID`[Required content]`Point Name`.

Comment: You could use a non capturing group with an optional newline `Point ID(\S.*?)[\r\n]*Point Name\b` https://regex101.com/r/FS2HdC/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use match the optional newline before matching *Point Name*.

For the required content part, you could match at least a single non whitespace char `\S` after *Point ID*.

```
Point ID(\S.*?)[\r\n]*Point Name\b
```

**The pattern matches**

- `Point ID` Match literaly
- `(\S.*?)` Capture **group 1**, match a non whitespace char and any char except a newline non greedy
- `[\r\n]*` Match 0+ newlines
- `Point Name\b` Match Point Name followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FS2HdC/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jgc97v)

```
import re

def extract_id(sent):
    regex = r"Point ID(\S.*?)[\r\n]*Point Name\b"
    return re.findall(regex, sent)

sent1 = 'Date:2020/07/11 13:53  Low Alarm OFF\nAlarm Priority:Urgent\nPoint ID0000294.AI.0017707\nPoint Name:BOM-DC3-B2-2F-Q1-TEMP 3\nAlarm:Normal\nStatus:18.6 øC'
sent2 = 'Date:2020/07/11 13:42  Low AlarmAlarm Priority:UrgentPoint ID0000294.AI.0017707Point Name:BOM-DC3-B2-2F-Q1-TEMP 3Alarm:AbnormalStatus:Analog Lower Limit Alarm 18.0 øC'

print(extract_id(sent1))
print(extract_id(sent2))
```

Output

```
['0000294.AI.0017707']
['0000294.AI.0017707']
```

Comment: We can also use id = re.compile(r"Point ID(\S.*?)[\r\n]*Point Name\b") to optimize response time.